# Magnetizing inductance Vs. mutual inductance

Tags: transformer

1. In the transformer equivalent circuit model, is the magnetizing reactance/inductance the same as the transformer's mutual reactance/inductance?
2. Does the secondary have a magnetizing reactance? Is this the same thing as the primary magnetizing reactance, or are they lumped into one quantity called Xm?

Comment: Is there none that can answer this seemingly simple question?

Answer (score 4):

I've seen the terms mutual and magnetizing inductance used interchangeably, but I don't believe them to be the same.  Mutual inductance can be derived if you consider a simple magnetic circuit with two separately excited coils (such as the one shown here: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/transf.html).  The flux linkage in coil 2 that is produced by the current flowing in coil 1 is related to mutual inductance (\$\lambda_{21} = L_{21}*i_1\$, where \$"L_{21}"\$ is the mutual inductance term).  You can derive the same relationship for the flux linking coil 1 due to the current in coil 2 (\$\lambda_{12} = L_{12}*i_2\$).  In theory, \$L_{12} = L_{21}\$ = the mutual inductance.

Magnetizing inductance is associated with the flux that actually links the core of the transformer (as opposed to leakage flux, which does not).  If you're familiar with the 'open circuit test' for a transformer that's used to measure Xm, think about how the test is performed.  The secondary is left open while rated voltage is applied to the primary.  This test actually measures primary side leakage and magnetizing reactance, but the former is typically assumed to be much smaller, and is therefore neglected.  This is more closely related to the self-inductance of one side (in this case the primary) of the transformer.

The Magnetizing inductance / reactance can be referred to either the primary or the secondary of the transformer.  For example, if you use the open circuit test as described above, you would include it in the primary of your model.  You can then use the turns ratio to refer it to the secondary.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a picture that might help: -

[image]

It's basically two coupled inductors aka a transformer. L1 is the primary and L2 is the secondary. With L2 open circuit, L1 always measures the same irrespective of the L2's distance.

Mutual inductance of two coils that are 100% coupled (like a perfect transformer) is: -

[image]

Given that primary magnetizing inductance is L1, M *can* equal L1 when L1 = L2. Pretty pictures taken from [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/inductor/mutual-inductance.html)

Answer (score 2):

To give some short answers first:

1. Magnetising inductance and mutual inductance are not the same.
2. The magetising inductance is conventionally added to the primary, and there will be no inductance on the secondary. The magetising inductance is a lumped parameter.

In detail (Figures are my own):

### Mutual inductance

[image: mutual inductance]

Consider Ampere's law to determine the magnetomotive force in the core:
$$
\phi \mathcal{R}_c = N_1 i_1 - N_2 i_2 \quad \Rightarrow \quad \phi = \frac{N_1 i_1 - N_2 i_2}{\mathcal{R}_c}
$$
We have two windings with \$N_1\$ and \$N_2\$ number of turns and one circuit, or core, with reluctance \$\mathcal{R}_c\$, and the flux \$\phi\$ links the two coils.

For the first windind we have
$$
\phi_1 = \phi
$$
and
for the second winding we have
$$
\phi_2 = -\phi
$$
due to the right hand rule and the choices of the directions of currents and polarities of voltages (see the Figure).

Faraday's law then gives us
$$
v_1 = N_1 \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_1}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{N_1}{\mathcal{R}_c} \left( N_1 \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d} t} - N_2 \frac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d} t} \right) = \left( \frac{{N_1}^2}{\mathcal{R}_c} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d} t} - \left( \frac{N_1 N_2}{\mathcal{R}_c} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
$$
v_2 = -N_2 \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_2}{\mathrm{d} t} = -\frac{N_2}{\mathcal{R}_c} \left( N_1 \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d} t} - N_2 \frac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d} t} \right) = -\left( \frac{N_1 N_2}{\mathcal{R}_c} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d} t} + \left( \frac{{N_2}^2}{\mathcal{R}_c} \right) \frac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
which we can simplify somewhat to
$$
v_1 = L_1 \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d} t} - M \frac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
$$
v_2 = -M \frac{\mathrm{d} i_1}{\mathrm{d} t} + L_2 \frac{\mathrm{d} i_2}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
where \$L_1 = {{N_1}^2}/{\mathcal{R}_c}\$, \$L_2 = {{N_2}^2}/{\mathcal{R}_c}\$ are the self inductances, and \$M = \sqrt{L_1 L_2}\$. The parameter \$M\$ is sometimes referred to as *mutual inductance*.

### Magnetising inductance

[image: magnetising inductance]

There is another formulation that uses a *magnetising current* and *magnetising inductance* in an attempt to simplify the expressions.

We rewrite the expression for the flux as
$$
\phi = \frac{N_1 i_1 - N_2 i_2}{\mathcal{R}_c} = \frac{N_1 i_m}{\mathcal{R}_c}
$$
where we have implicitly defined the *magnetising current*
$$
i_m = i_1 - \frac{N_2}{N_1} i_2 \ .
$$

The voltages at the terminals are then given as
$$
v_1 = N_1 \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_1}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{{N_1}^2}{\mathcal{R}_c} \frac{\mathrm{d} i_m}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
$$
v_2 = -N_2 \frac{\mathrm{d} \phi_2}{\mathrm{d} t} = \frac{N_1 N_2}{\mathcal{R}_c} \frac{\mathrm{d} i_m}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
For the coil 1 the expression is further simplied as
$$
v_1 = L_m \frac{\mathrm{d} i_m}{\mathrm{d} t}
$$
where
$$
L_m = \frac{{N_1}^2}{\mathcal{R}_c}
$$
is called the *magnetising inductance*. For coil 2 we can write
$$
v_2 = \frac{N_2}{N_1} L_m \frac{\mathrm{d} i_m}{\mathrm{d} t} \ .
$$

### Summary

- Mutual inductance is defined as \$M = \sqrt{L_1 L_2}\$.
- Magnetising inductance is defined as \$L_m = L_1 = \frac{{N_1}^2}{\mathcal{R}_c}\$.
- They are not the same and correspond to different formulations.

Answer (score 1):

(1) They aren't the same. Only when turns ratio=1.
(2) In the transformer model, there only have one magnetizing inductance, usually "put on" the primary side. When you derive the secondary voltage(combine the magnetizing inductance and leakage inductance of both side), you will find the voltage of secondary is derived from the magnetizing voltage in the primary.

Answer (score -1):

Since there is no current flowing on the HV side, there should be no mutual inductance, and the Magnetizing inductance should simply be equal to the self inductance of the LV coil (neglecting leakage inductance of course), not mutual inductance.